# Cannot compile mergevec.cpp from Haartraining tutorial

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opencv, g++, compilation

I have been following this tutorial ( http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html ) to do some Haar training.  I am currently stuck on creating the training samples, specifically the combining of the .vec files.  I am provided with this ( http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining/mergevec.cpp.html ) file and a description of how to build it for Linux (Ubuntu 11.04).  Here lies my problem, I am unable to build the mergevec code.  The only error is "fatal error: cvhaartraining.h: No such file or directory."  I have checked to make sure that cvhaartraining.h is in the same directory as mergevec but have found everything to be right where I would expect it.  At this point, I am at a loss of how to solve this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `-I.` to your compilation flags.

Comment: Same problem here, where exactly should I add `-I`?
original build command: `g++ \`pkg-config --cflags opencv\` \`pkg-config --libs opencv\` -o mergevec mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp`

Answer (score 4):

For building mergevec I found that the easiest way was to edit CMake configuration files. In OpenCV 2.3.1, the `haartraining` directory is in `modules/haartraining` whereas in 2.4.5 it is in `apps/haartraining.` Either way, the file you are interested in editing is called `CMakeLists.txt`.

The easiest thing to do is to add a special section for mergevec, as follows:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------
#  mergevec
# -----------------------------------------------------------
add_executable(opencv_mergevec mergevec.cpp)
set_target_properties(opencv_mergevec PROPERTIES
                      DEBUG_POSTFIX "${OPENCV_DEBUG_POSTFIX}"
                      OUTPUT_NAME "opencv_mergevec")
```

You can add this right before the installation section. Then place `mergevec.cpp` into the `haartraining` directory, build OpenCV normally, and you will have an `opencv_mergevec` binary which is the `mergevec.cpp` executable.

Answer (score 1):

For others struggling with this on Ubuntu, move the flags to the end of the invocation, like this:

```
g++ -I. -o mergevec mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem type the following:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -I. -o mergevec mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp cvhaarclassifier.cpp haartraining.cpp   -lopencv_core -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

Good Luck
Ibrahim