# How to compile mergevec.cpp on Windows?

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, g++, cygwin

I have been following this tutorial ( http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html ) to do some Haar training. I am currently stuck on merging the generate *.vec files.  I am provided with this ( http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining/mergevec.cpp.html ) script and a description of how to build it for Linux, but for Linux only.

I have installed Cygwin, placed mergevec.cpp file into openCV_dir/apps/haartraining and tried to compile it with the following command:

```
$ g++ 'pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv' -I. -o mergevec mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp
```

I recieve following error:

```
$ g++: error: pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv: No such file or directory
```

Could someone tell me how should I properly compile it for Windows?

Working on Windows 7, Cygwin x64, OpenCV 2.4.6

Comment: Adding it to the opencv build worked for me on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079504/cannot-compile-mergevec-cpp-from-haartraining-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get mergevec.exe from here:

http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining/mergevec.cpp.html

It requires highgui100.dll and cxcore100.dll which I downloaded from:

http://www.dllme.com/